# WindowBuilder debug mode dies with 503

Tags: java, gxt, windowbuilder

I'm running WindowBuilder building a GXT application under eclipse. It's a new app, but has been working before I gutted and rebuilt my first form.

Now when it comes up in my Firefox window, it says:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

RequestURI=/ImageViewer.html

Powered by jetty://
```

For url: http://127.0.0.1:8888/ImageViewer.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Any ideas?

Comment: The URL is a link to your local webserver. Only you can access it from your computer. Take a scree shot or host the webpage elsewhere. (aka: We can't access the URL)

Comment: A screen shot of what? This is the entire page. I'm not getting any sort of other errors, so I have no idea what's going on. I'm sure at this point it's something stupid, but...

Comment: The URL you gave us isn't an online web link. You need to give us something to look at, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: You sure have in your eclipse console a more detailed description of your error. Try to post that here because from the provided info we can't see the problem either.

Comment: @Catalin Yes, I think it has something to do with Spring. I backed off and started from scratch and its where I put spring into it that everything fell apart. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that all of these issues were because of mis-configuration of the spring framework from the web.xml file and then missing jar files from spring framework.

When I resolved all of these, my GXT app started working properly.

thanks for all the help